# Hiding .children is easy - what about <dd> that belong to a <dt>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This code provides a simple rollover/rollout show|hide feature:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[class='lineItem']").hover(function () {

        $(this).children(".hiddenDesc").css("visibility", "visible");
    },
function () {
    $(this).children(".hiddenDesc").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
});
```

How can i provide similar to functionality to a structure like:

```
    <dl>
        <dt>
            High-level stuff 1
        </dt>
        <dd class="hiddenDesc">
            Extended explanatory stuff that goes on seemingly forever 1
        </dd>
        <dt>
            High-level stuff 2
        </dt>
        <dd class="hiddenDesc">
            Extended explanatory stuff that goes on seemingly forever 2
        </dd>
        <dt>
            High-level stuff 3
        </dt>
        <dd class="hiddenDesc">
            Extended explanatory stuff that goes on seemingly forever 3
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

Comment: @Sean - since the code-syntax highlighting changes, be sure to tag something with `html` if it has HTML in it, not *only* JavaScript, since it'll throw the highlighting off.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Wow, I didn't know tags influenced the SO syntax highlighter. That's very nifty.

Comment: @Bolt See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Are you really wanting to use visibility to hide it? doesn't that leave a blank space where it is hidden? I beleive you might want display: none / block. and thus use jquery .show or .hide or .toggle.

Comment: Was saving that to impress the boss with Version 2. thankx for letting the cat out of the bag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), just use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("dt").hover(function () {
    $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function () {
    $(this).next().css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yRZxJ/), for related questions about DOM navigation, moving from one element to another, be sure to check out the [tree-traversal section of the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: i have seen my mistake; deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a little more complex that it seems - multiple `dt` elements can be used in combination with multiple `dd` elements, so you'll have to use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) in combination with the [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector):

```
$('dt').hover(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

CSS:

```
dd {
    visibility: hidden;
}

dd.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Of course, if you're HTML isn't that complex, then [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561857/hiding-children-is-easy-what-about-dd-that-belong-to-a-dt/4561868#4561868) will do nicely. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/EA4R5/4/ for a simple demo of this.